# Can we Fire the button CLick event on Windowload In WPf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, button

i want to FIre the button Click event When My Window is Loaded..
How Can i Achieve it in Wpf?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a single function with the shared behavior in your window, then call that function from both your loaded handler and your click handler.

Answer (score 6):

As per [this blog post](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/03/09/how-to-programmatically-click-a-button/) in WinForms this was really easy by just calling PerformClick(), but in WPF you can do it with Automation, however as a commenter mentioned it's really easy if you have access to the button to just use `RaiseEvent`.

```
someButton.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
```

But as previously answered, if you only have a single handler that needs to be notified, then simply call that handler method directly.

Answer (score 0):

in you page_loaded event handler method, make a call to the click event like this:

> _buttonName_click(sender, new RoutedEventArgs())

Comment: To clarify, this isn't actually calling the 'event'... It's calling the method (which happens to also be a handler for the click event). But yes, this is correct way to do it if we know this is the only handler we need to call to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Automation` to do it aswell - I've seen this suggested some places as the more flexible/robust method to use, but it seems a bit heavy weight to me compared to just calling the method you already have directly.

Answer (score 0):

Trgger this event on Button whic u wanted to click
button.performclick();